# How scroll the viewport together with transition effect?

Tags: javascript, html, css

in the following example there are several DIVs that use transition effect, how can you scroll the 
viewport up and down smoothly with the expansion so that the user can always see the full square?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) does the trick? You'll need a mouseenter listener too, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the best solution, of course, in my opinion , is using  `new ResizeObserver()`

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll("div");
const resizeObserve = new ResizeObserver((entries) => {
  entries.forEach(({ target }) =>
    target.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "nearest",
      inline: "nearest"
    })
  );
});
divs.forEach((item) => {
  resizeObserve.observe(item);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>

</body>
</html>
```

you can do that only with `scrollIntoView` too.

```js
const divs = document.querySelectorAll('div')
divs.forEach(item=>{
  item.addEventListener('mouseenter',(e)=>{
   e.currentTarget.addEventListener('transitionend',(e)=>{
  e.currentTarget.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "nearest", inline: "nearest"});
   })
  })
})
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style> 
div {
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: #0000ff;
 transition: 0.5s;
}

div:hover {
  background-color: #ffcccc;
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
<div>4</div>
<div>5</div>
<div>6</div>
<div>7</div>
<div>8</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @postFix use second solution

Comment: You can observe multiple elements with the same observer. There is no need to instantiate a new one for every child.

Comment: @Ahmad MRF
Works great! Is there an option to make the movement more smoother?
It moves to the right place but sometimes it feels like it moves "frame by frame"